# Visa Free Countries for Romanian Residence Holder

Tags: pakistani-citizens, visa-free-entry, romania

Hi I am Pakistani national and working in Romania. I have residence permit long term. please advise which countries I can travel visa free with Romanian residence permit. thanks

Comment: Your question is very broad, it might help if you narrowed it down to a particular region(s).

Comment: Did you bother a google atleast ?

Comment: You Passport remains  your main travelling document. So you first look based on your citizenship and then if any exceptions exist based on the Residence permit. With a Schengen Area Residence permit, you would not need a visa, but still need to travel with the passport.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an article in [Visa requirements for Pakistani citizens](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Pakistani_citizens) which at the time of writing lists 31 countries that are visa-free or visa-on-arrival for Pakistanis.

As Romania is not yet part of the Schengen area your Romanian residence permit doesn't allow you access to Schengen countries, but according to the Wikipedia article on the [Schengen Visa Policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Residents_and_holders_of_visas_of_Schengen_states) you can enter Bulgaria, Croatia and Cyprus.

Your question is, however, rather broad and I don't claim that this answer is exhaustive. If there is some country you'd like to visit you would do better asking about the specific visa requirements for that country.

Comment: It is very difficult for nationals of some countries to obtain visas to many places, so when looking for a place to go on holiday, they often prefer to look for places which they can enter more easily, and then choose a destination from among such countries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I get that, but narrowing the field even to a general area would be a big help to someone trying to answer.